# WKWebView load request in device not working, but simulator is working

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I have a question about WKWebview.
First, I have a UITabbarViewController(tab1, tab2), and two ViewControllers.
In ViewController1 have two button (button1, button2) which action is click the tabbar tab2 to present the ViewController2 and bring different url string.
In ViewController2 have a WKWebView, and load the request of url string.
I work fine in simulator, but build in device and work fine at first time and the then I tap the tabbar tab1 and back to ViewController1.
I click the button2 and present the ViewController2.
And I also set breakpoint, the WKWebview have run the load request function.
But the WKWebview also show me the button1 url content, not button2 url content. When I back and click button2 again, it's work. Why the WKWebView don't refresh at first time?
 
Thanks. 
Xcode 9.4.1, device iOS 12.0.1(16A404)

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

@objc func btnTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    if let vc = self.navigationController?.parent as? ViewController {
        if let number = item?.number {

            let domainPath = “\(customURL!.absoluteString)"
            let extPath = "detail/\(number)/&topPageBack=list"
            let encodestr = extPath.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
            let finalPath = domainPath.appending("/").appending(encodestr!)

            if let url = URL(string: finalPath) {
                vc.loadSpecificURL = url
            }
            vc.tabBarView.buttonClick(tag: 1)
        }
    }
}
}
```

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

lazy var webViewController: CustomWKWebViewController = {
    let controller = CustomWKWebViewController()
    controller.wKWebViewPage = .searchPage
    return controller
}()

var loadURL: URL?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let url = loadURL {
        webViewController.reloadWebView(url: url)
        loadURL = nil
    }

}

}
```

```
class CustomWKWebViewController: UIViewController {

private func settingWebView() -> WKWebView {
    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)

    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    userContentController.add(self, name: "Login")  
    userContentController.add(self, name: "Other")
    userContentController.add(self, name: “LD”)
    userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)                     

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()                   
    config.userContentController = userContentController

    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    webView!.navigationDelegate = self
    webView!.uiDelegate = self
    webView!.scrollView.bounces = false
    webView!.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webView!.backgroundColor = .clear
    webView!.scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear

    if let request = getRequest() {
        webView!.load(request)
    }
    return webView!
}

func reloadWebView(url: URL?) {

    if let url = url, let webView = self.webView {
        var requestForBlank = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "about:blank")!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 3)
        requestForBlank.httpMethod = "POST"

        var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 3)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        webView.load(requestForBlank)
        webView.load(request)//breakpoint always break here, but the view don't load request.
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I just call webView.load(request) twice and it's work. Why???

Answer (score 2):

First you check if web url not nil, then also call the else part of if.

```
if let url = webview.url {
    webview.reload()
} else {
    webview.load(URLRequest(url: originalURL))
}
```